# Making a Cloudinary grid of headshots

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary for image storage and manipulation. In one place I'm creating a grid (2x2) of headshots. This:

```
cloudinary.url(images[0], {transformation: [
  {width:90, height:90, crop:'fill'},
  {overlay:images[1], width:90, height:90, x:90, crop:"fill"},
  {overlay:images[2], width:90, height:90, y:90, x:-45, crop:"fill"},
  {overlay:images[3], width:90, height:90, y:45, x:45, crop:"fill"},
  {width:180, height:180, crop:"crop"},
]});
```

seems to work.

In the rest of the app I use Cloudinary's face recognition (`gravity:"face"`) to crop the headshots, and would like to do the same for each of the quadrants of the grid. But the docs define the `gravity` param as:

> Decides which part of the image to keep while the 'crop', 'pad', 'thumb' and 'fill' crop modes are used. **For overlays, this decides where to place the overlay**.

What do they mean "for overlays, this decides where to place the overlay"? How do I use gravity to control the crop of an overlay, then position four of them in a grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you use `gravity` on an overlay, Cloudinary then place the overlay accordingly on the main image (e.g., `g_south_east` will position the overlay image on the south-east corner of the underlying image).
If you want to apply the gravity to the overlay itself, then you'll need to instruct Cloudinary accordingly. This is done by using the `layer_apply` flag (`fl_layer_apply` in the URL, see [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference#flags_parameter) for doc).

Try this:

```
cloudinary.url(images[0], {transformation: [
  {width:90, height:90, crop:'fill'},
  {overlay:images[1], width:90, height:90, crop:"fill", gravity:"face"},
  {x:90, flags:"layer_apply"},
  {overlay:images[2], width:90, height:90, y:90, x:-45, crop:"fill", gravity:"face"},
  {y:90, x:-45, flags:"layer_apply"},
  {overlay:images[3], width:90, height:90, y:45, x:45, crop:"fill", gravity:"face"},
  {y:45, x:45, flags:"layer_apply"},
  {width:180, height:180, crop:"crop"}
]});
```